# Какой язык используется в файле .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

И где можно найти материалы для изучения?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Я сначала думал что XML

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: `htaccess` - это файл-конфигуратор Apache-серверов. собственно логично смотреть инфу на сайте апача

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файлах .htaccess нет "языка программирования", скорее это синтаксис конфигурационного файла - директивы:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html

Исполняемого кода в этом файле нет, там хранятся инструкции для настроек сервера. Другое дело, на какой базе .htaccess составлен. В нем есть некоторые вещи и от XML, и от регулярных выражений. Также в него включен синтаксис настройки PHP и некоторых других языков.